# How to get ID of newly created object in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get ID of a newly created object after the super call

```
ActiveAdmin.register Account do
   .
   .
   .
 controller do
   def create
        .
        .
        .
     super
     // Get ID of the newly created Account object. I'm not sure if calling Account.last is reliable?
```

Comment: `Account.last` is not reliable: if another `Account` is created elsewhere in the app between creating this one and retrieving its ID, you'll have incorrect data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know whether the creation is successful, I call resource.valid? and to get the ID, I call resource.id

Answer (score 0):

Yes account.last is also fine. But you can create a method in your model to get created account id.

```
  after_save {id = self.id}
```